# First-order Differential Equation on Exam Explanation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm taking an elementary differential equations class and we got our first exam back and I don't understand why I was wrong on one of the questions. I got a 96, and the professor said there were quite a few d's and f's, so I didn't want to quibble about this.

Anyway, the problem was $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{x+y+2}$ and I chose the sub $u = x+y+2$, with $ \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{du}\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{du}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{u}\right)$ and then plugged in the expression for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, separated the equation and solved for $y$ in terms of $u$ and then substituted back to get $y = \ln (x+y+3)+ c.$
The professor took issue with my expression for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, saying that I couldn't differentiate $y$ w.r.t. $u$ if $y$ is part of $u.$ Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution seems fine, although it is an implicit solution. I think an easier way to solve the DE
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x+y+2}$$
is to arrange as 
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=x+y+2.$$
This is a first-order linear equation for $x(y).$ I get
$$x(y)=C e^y-y-3.$$
It's possible to solve for $y$ using the Lambert $W$ function, but it's rather messy and doesn't provide as much insight.

Comment: It actually does provide some insight if you know a bit about the properties of Lambert W, but in elementary courses the solution is generally left in implicit form.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$u=x+y+2$$

$$\frac {du}{dx}= 1+ \frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$\frac {du}{dx}=1+\frac {1}{u}$$

$$\frac {udu}{u+1} =dx$$
$$u-\ln (u+1)=x+c$$

$$x+y+2 = x+ \ln (x+y+3)+c$$
$$y=\ln(x+y+3)+c$$

Comment: How do you get that $\ln(u)$?  $\int \frac{1}{u}\; du = \ln(u)$, but here you're integrating with respect to $x$.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct.  There should be no problem in regarding $u$ as the independent variable (unless it turns out to be constant).